# Rails server not working after changing gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

After I changed my Gemfile in rails and ran `bundle install` and `update`, I tried to run the `rails s` but then I got this error:

```
C:\Users\alouf\Sites\fapp>rails s C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `require': cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:16:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11-x64-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
        from C:/Users/alouf/Sites/fapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '5.0.3'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.1.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.40.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',                    '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.6.1'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
gem 'guard',                    '2.14.1'
gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end 

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: You problem is not in the whole `Gemfile` but in `bcrypt` gem. Check this issue https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/128

Comment: try "gem uninstall bcrypt" then "gem install bcrypt" after that "bundle install".

Comment: Just curious, but why are you using such strict versioning in your `Gemfile`?